# Get pointer to array held in super class

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

Studying polymorphism in objective c . I'm trying to do some things using an `NSMutableArray` that is held by my super class, so I need a pointer to it from the sub class.

SuperViewController.h

```
@interface SuperViewController : UIViewController
- (NSMutableArray *) myArray;
@end
```

SuperViewController.m

```
@interface SuperViewController()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

@implementation SuperViewController

- (NSMutableArray *) myArray {return self.myArray;}
@end
```

Then, in my subclass, I have this:

SubViewController.h

```
#import SuperViewController.h

@interface SubViewController : SuperViewController
- (void) updateUI;
@end
```

SubViewController.m

```
@implementation
- (void) updateUI
{
    (NSMutableArray *) myArray = [super myArray];
}
@end
```

It crashes the App . I've tried quite a few different approaches, but I always wind up crashing. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Crash or compile error?

Comment: Crash! It compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that you have a recursion which blows the stack:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) myArray 
{
    return self.myArray;
}
```

This method calls itself. The dot notation is a short form of method invocation:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) myArray 
{
    return [self myArray];
}
```

It is *not* an access to the object's context (ivar) as you probably expected:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) myArray 
{
    return self->_myArray;
}
```

The right way is to use the ivar directly:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) myArray 
{
    return _myArray;
}
```

BTW:

1. Properties can have the `readonly` attribute.
2. Using `super` in the derived class is useless and dangerous. It does not use the super's context (which does not exist, because every instance object has only *one* context built from the whole class hierarchy), but uses the super implementation of the method. You did not overwrite this implementation in the derived class. `self` would work, too, and gives you the ability to overwrite the getter.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely the issue. I'm still confused about these implicit getter methods in Objective C. I'm used to Java where we explicitly write getters. Thank you very much!

Comment: Every _ in the answer should not be there.

Comment: @CRD the property is auto synthesized.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - Sorry, it was just the first one. As I'm now on a real keyboard I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You've written `self.myArray` to access an instance variable. The dot notation is a *property* access, and will invoke a property-like method even if not declared as a property. In your case this means your attempt to access the instance variable is in fact a self-recursive call, which will result in stack overflow.

To access an instance variable either use just it's name or the `->` member access operator, e.g. `_myArray` or `self->_myArray`.

Comment: What I want to know is: how does `(NSMutableArray *) myArray = [super myArray];` compile??

Comment: @fumoboy007 - `super` specifies that the search for a method implementation should begin in the superclass. It is usually used when a method is overridden and there is a need to call the original method. However there is no requirement that a method *must* be overridden to use `super` - it just makes no difference in that case.

Comment: No I meant the left side of the assignment. Where is `myArray` coming from?

Comment: @fumoboy007 - I see your point. I just assume it's an instance variable, the cast being redundant, or was intended as a local variable declaration and the OP typed the parentheses into the question by mistake. Its probably code cut, or made up from, some larger real code and mistakes happen when doing so, such is life!

Comment: Lolz so I'm not going crazy! =)